# overload resolution for template functions with non template type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, sfinae

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_lvalue_reference_of_type =
    std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, U>::value;

// container is lvalue reference and no filter, echo back parameter
template <typename Container,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
                is_lvalue_reference_of_type<Container, std::vector<int>>
            >
          >
const std::vector<int>& f(void *, Container && c)
{
    std::cout << "void *\n";
    return c;
}
// filter input and return a copy
template <typename Filter,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Filter>, void *>>>
std::vector<int> f(Filter &&, const std::vector<int> &)
{
    std::cout << "Filter \n";
    return {};
}
}


template <typename T = void*>
void g(T && t = nullptr)
{
    const std::vector<int> v;
    detail::f(std::forward<T>(t), v);
}

int main(int, const char * const * const)
{
    g();
    g([](const int) {return true;});
}
```

Is there a way of automatically preferring the first template overload when arguments of type ***`void*`, `const std::vector<int> &`*** are passed without manually excluding the second overload for this combination? I find it redundant to manually disable the second overload since the first overload already specifies a non template type first parameter as ***`void*`***. The goal is to have one overload that does no filtering and echo back the input but only iff it is an lvalue reference (not an rvalue bound to `const &`) and another overload that does filtering and returns a copy.

Comment: The overload resolution tries to find a function that is the best match for *all* parameters. But obviously, the first function matches `void*` exactly. And the second function is more specialized for the second parameter, and matches the vector.  So no best choice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of automatically preferring the first template overload when arguments of type ***`void*`, `const std::vector &`*** are passed without manually excluding the second overload for this combination?

Maybe you can add a third unused argument, `int` in first overload and `long` in second, and call `f()` with a `0` (a `int` value) to give precedence to first one.

The following is a full example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename Container>
   std::vector<int> const & f (void *, Container && c, int)
    { std::cout << "void *\n"; return c; }

   template <typename Filter>
   std::vector<int> f (Filter &&, std::vector<int> const &, long)
    { std::cout << "Filter \n"; return {}; }
 }


template <typename T = void*>
void g (T && t = nullptr)
 {
   std::vector<int> const v;
   detail::f(std::forward<T>(t), v, 0);
 }

int main ()
 {
   g();
   g([](int const) { return true; });
 }
```